# Who are these deities with Alakshmi?

Tags: identification-request, deity, alakshmi

In the below picture, i found Jyeshtha (Alakshmi) with other two deities, when i find to install better picture of Astha Lakshmi.

[image]

I wanted to know about who are these guys with Alakshmi (in middle). So my question is, Who are them?

Comment: There is a chapter dedicated to her origin and worship in [linga purana Part - 2, Chapter 6](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-linga-purana/d/doc1196095.html) , But could not find anything related to that.

Answer (score 1):

As the [inscription of Rājarāja](https://archive.org/details/in.gov.ignca.79603/page/n66/mode/1up?view=theater) reiterates, the exact imagery is from Tirupparaṅkuṉṟam's courtyard dedicated to Seṭṭhaiyar or Jyeṣṭhādevī. Kṛṣṇa śāstrī
while mentioning the same in his '[South-Indian images of God and Goddess](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.103546/page/n235/mode/1up?view=theater)' states that the one on her right side with a bull-faced figure is said to be her son, while on the left is believed to be her daughter.

This is further clarified by the quotation of Pūrva Kāraṇāgama, while discussing the iconography of Jyeṣṭhādevī in [Vāstuśāstra (*ed. D.N Śukla*)](https://archive.org/details/GYxw_vastu-shastra-vol.-2-hindu-canons-of-iconography-and-painting-by-dr.-d.-n.-shukl/page/n795/mode/1up?view=theater): *kanyāputrānvitā devī dakṣiṇe'dakṣiṇe'pi ca* (कन्यापुत्रान्विता देवी दक्षिणेऽदक्षिणेऽपि च ।). [Elements Of Hindu Iconography](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.459193/page/n171/mode/1up) by T.A Gopīnātha Rao while quoting the same agama also quotes another one named Aṃśumadbhedāgama, wherein the daughter is called Agnimātā. The common names for the duo though, are Vṛṣa or Lulāpamukha (for the bull-headed son) and Mānyā or Raktajyeṣṭha (for the daughter).

Lastly, while the section concerning the origin story of Jyeṣṭhādevī and her offspring in Ajitamahātantra is [not preserved well](https://manasataramgini.wordpress.com/2010/06/23/jyeshtha-in-shivalaya-s/); there exist verses for Sthāpana Vidhāna in multiple texts like the one quoted afore.

Comment: I found Purva-Karanagama and Ajitamahatantra   but cannot see Amsumadbhedagama. So, Can you pls provide the link of Amsumadbhedagama.

Comment: I don't have access to any e-version of Aṃśumadbhedāgama; I merely quoted T.A Gopīnātha Rao who in turn has quoted the agama. Although I was able to find Kāśyapaśilpam, which is said to be Pratimālakṣaṇa portion of the said agama. I guess the verse quoted belong to this portion: https://archive.org/details/ananda-ashram/ASS_095_Kasyapasilpam_-_Krishnaraya_Vajhe_1926/mode/2up?view=theater